Is there a way to install a Github App on only public repositories in a Github organization?
I have a Github App with specific repository permissions that I need to install only on public repositories in my Github organization. I could do this manually and go into each public repository's settings and install the Github App but I was wondering if there is a programmatic or an automatic way of doing this. I haven't been able to find any other posts about this specific use case.
There is a Github API endpoint for adding a repository to an app installation (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/apps/installations?apiVersion=2022-11-28#add-a-repository-to-an-app-installation). So I could make a Github API call to get my organization's public repos and then call this API endpoint for each of those repos but I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this. Especially if a new public repo is created and needs to automatically have this Github App installed.
